# Read a variable from a different Class in Actionscript 3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash-cs5

I have already set a variable in my document class "Main.as". I am now trying to access that variable and read its value from a different Class and Function, take that value and email it.

For example in my "Main.as" file I have this function:

```
public var _myVar:String;

function create() {
    _myVar = "hello";
}
```

Now from my other class "EmailtoFriend.as" I have a new function to try and get the value of that pre set variable:

```
function getVar() {
    trace(_myVar);
}
```

Why will it not output "hello"? Instead I get an error saying: Access of undefined property _myVar. If I could just get this simple example working, I think it will help me understand a lot of things. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error your getting really says it all. Although `_myVar` is defined in your `Main` class `public var _myVar:String;`, it isn't defined in your `Emailtofriend` class. If you want access to `_myVar` you need to do one of the following:

Parse a reference of your `Main` object(using `this`) to your `EmailToFriend` class:

**Main.as(document class)**:

```
package 
{
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.events.Event;

    public class Main extends Sprite 
    {
        public var _myVar:String;

        public function Main():void 
        {
            if (stage) init();
            else addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, init);

        }// end function

        public function create():void
        {
            _myVar = "hello";

        }// end function

        private function init(e:Event = null):void 
        {
            removeEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, init);

            create();

            var emailToFriend:EmailToFriend = new EmailToFriend(this);
            emailToFriend.getVar();

        }// end function

    }// end class

}// end package

internal class EmailToFriend
{
    private var _main:Main;

    public function EmailToFriend(main:Main)
    {
        _main = main;

    }// end function

    public function getVar():void
    {
        trace(_main._myVar);

    }// end function

}// end class
```

Or to make `_myVar` a public static property of `Main` and access it via `Main._myVar`:

**Main.as(document class)**:

```
package 
{
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.events.Event;

    public class Main extends Sprite 
    {
        public static var _myVar:String;

        public function Main():void 
        {
            if (stage) init();
            else addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, init);

        }// end function

        public function create():void
        {
            _myVar = "hello";

        }// end function

        private function init(e:Event = null):void 
        {
            removeEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, init);

            create();

            var emailToFriend:EmailToFriend = new EmailToFriend();
            emailToFriend.getVar();

        }// end function

    }// end class

}// end package

internal class EmailToFriend
{
    public function EmailToFriend() {}

    public function getVar():void
    {
        trace(Main._myVar);

    }// end function

}// end class
```

Also one small thing, when using underscores for class properties, you should only use them for private properties, not public. Well I say **only** but I really mean it's more common.

**[UPDATE]**

This is in response to your comment:

**Main.as**:

```
package 
{
    import EmailToFriend;
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.events.Event;


    public class Main extends Sprite 
    {
        public static var _myVar:String;

        public function Main():void 
        {
            if (stage) init();
            else addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, init);

        }// end function

        public function create():void
        {
            _myVar = "hello";

        }// end function

        private function init(e:Event = null):void 
        {
            removeEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, init);

            create();

            var emailToFriend:EmailToFriend = new EmailToFriend();
            emailToFriend.getVar();

        }// end function

    }// end class

}// end package
```

**EmailToFriend.as**:

```
package  
{
    import Main;

    public class EmailToFriend 
    {
        public function EmailToFriend() {}

        public function getVar():void
        {
            trace(Main._myVar);

        }// end function

    }// end class

}// end package
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. I am assuming I need to put the internal class in my EmailtoFriend.as file? If so, I have done that and I am getting some errors:

1046: Type was not found or was not a compile-time constant: EmailToFriend.

1180: Call to a possibly undefined method EmailToFriend.

Comment: @Brandon did you import your `EmailToFriend` class into your `Main` class? also did you remember to change `internal` to `public`?

Comment: Yes, I have changed my EmailToFriend class to public, instead of internal and I also added "import EmailtoFriend;" underneath my other imports at the top of Main.as. I am getting the same 2 errors.

Comment: @Brandon you must be doing something different, look at my updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

All variables implicitly have a target, unless explicitly specified. Variables without an explicit target will commonly look in the local scope of the function (in this case, `getVar()`) and the global scope of the class (in this case, `EmailToFriend`).

I assume that these don't exist in your code, judging by the error. You will need something like the following to access the var:

```
function getVar() {
    var main:Main = new Main();
    main.create();
    trace(main._myVar);
}
```

Comment: Im getting an error "1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference."

Comment: Which line is this error associated to? The object declaration or the trace? Also, are your objects in the same package?

Comment: The error is occurring at line "var main:Main = new Main();"

They are in the same package:

package  {
  public class Main extends MovieClip {  
  
 public var _myVar:String;

 function create() {
  _myVar = "hello";
 }

Comment: Ok, Main and Emailtofriend are 2 separate packages/as files. Im sorry for my ignorance, but I am learning. So both of my as files are in my .fla root directory. "Path.To.Package.Main" I need to add this line to the top of my "EmailtoFriend" file? Where exactly does this go? After the package { ?

Comment: Odd, it should pick it up. For debugging purposes, try moving the class `Main` to a different package (and relative file location). Then use the `import` command at the top of `Emailtofriend`. If that `import` command errors, then it's something to do with the package declarations.

Comment: No worries, it's perfectly possible to have two seperate classes/files in the same package.

Comment: Ok Goran, I have tried to rebuild my test app with your suggestions. Here is my EmailtoFriend.as code: 

`package {
public class EmailtoFriend {
public function EmailtoFriend() {
   //trace("Email to Friend Loaded");

  }
  
  public function getVar() {
       var main:Main = new Main();
       trace(main._myVar);
   }
   getVar();
 }
}`

I am not seeing anything being traced in my output :(

Comment: Well at least it's not erroring, which must mean it's all linked up correctly. Have you called the method `.create()` anywhere in either class? I've updated the answer code to show how you can do so, if you haven't.

Comment: I have called the method `create()` just like your example, and I am still not seeing anything being traced. I also tried calling the `create()` method in my document class constructor and that didn't work either.

Answer (score 0):

```
  package {
    import flash.display.MovieClip;  
    public class Main extends MovieClip  {
       public var _myVar:String;
       public function Main(){
         create();
       }
       private function create() {
          _myVar = "hello";
         }
      }
      }
    }
```

in EmailtoFriend.a

```
import Main.as
var myMain = new Main();
trace(myMain._myVar);
```

Comment: Im getting an error "1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference."

Comment: in EmailtoFriend.as add `import Main.as`

Comment: Here is my Main.as:
    package  {
 
 import flash.display.*;
 import flash.events.*;
 
 
 public class Main extends MovieClip {

  public var _myVar:String;
  
  public function Main(){
   var test:EmailtoFriend = new EmailtoFriend();
   create();
  }


  private function create() {
   _myVar = "hello";
  }

  
 }
 
    }

Here is my EmailtoFriend.as:

    package {
 
 public class EmailtoFriend {
 
  public function EmailtoFriend() {

   var myMain = new Main();
   trace(myMain._myVar);
  }

 }
    }

Im getting a "Stack Overflow" error

Answer (score 0):

Assuming Main.as is your document class:

```
public var _myVar:String;

public function create():String {
//we specify that this function will return a String using the :String in the above line

    //now give the variable a value
    _myVar = "hello";

    //and send it back to the caller of the function
    return _myVar;
}
```

Within your other class

```
function getVar():void {

    //MovieClip(root) is another way of referencing your document class.
    trace(MovieClip(root).create());
}
```

OR...

```
public var _myVar:String;

public function create():void {

    //now give the variable a value
    _myVar = "hello";

}
```

Within your other class

```
function getVar():void {

    //call the function that actually gives myVar a value
    MovieClip(root).create();

    //now you can trace the value
    trace(MovieClip(root)._myVar);
}
```

Comment: Ok, I am trying your example and I am getting an error- "Access of undefined property root"

Here is my EmailtoFriend.as file:
<code>package {
 
 import flash.display.*;
 
 public class EmailtoFriend {
 
  public function EmailtoFriend() {
   //trace("Email Loaded");
  }
 
  public function getVar():void {

     //MovieClip(root) is another way of referencing your document class.
     trace(MovieClip(root).create());
  }
 }
}</code>

Answer (score 0):

What you should do is have a OOP approach, meaning use encapsulation in your classes. If you don;t know what that means, its ok. For instance, if you have a variable, that you want to be accessible, then you should really make it private, and the set up its own public function that returns the variable. Like this:

```
package {

public class SomeClass {
    private var someVar:Number = 12; // A private variable, which means only this class can
// use the reference someVar, and only other outiside classes can use the function getSomeVar.
    ... // skip some regular class stuff

    public function getSomeVar():Number {
        return this.someVar; //returns the variable someVar from this class to whoever is accessing it. 
//This function is public which means that anyone can call it and get the variable someVar.
    }
}
}
```

To access that variable, you just reference a class instance:

```
var someClass:SomeClass = new SomeClass(); // create the instance using the variable someClass
var myVar:Number = someClass.getSomeVar(); // ACCESSES the variable that you want from the class, 
//by first using the class instance reference, and then calling its public function that returns the value you want.
```